# Getting data using distinct in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has two columns, a date time and a string.

Multiple entries can have the same string, its a file path.

I want to return distinct entries with the latest date time stamp. Can anyone help me out here?

Cheers.

EDIT: Sample data

```
ExportedDate                CsvLocation
------------------------    --------------------------------------
2015-09-14 14:37:19.000     C:\fakePath\9_14_201514_56_35\file.txt
2015-09-14 14:53:25.000     C:\fakePath\9_14_201514_56_35\file.txt
2015-09-14 15:00:31.000     C:\fakePath\9_14_201514_56_35\file.txt
2015-09-14 15:54:42.000     C:\fakePath\9_14_201515_23_22\file.txt
```

Then I want returned:

```
2015-09-14 15:00:31.000     C:\fakePath\9_14_201514_56_35\file.txt
2015-09-14 15:54:42.000     C:\fakePath\9_14_201515_23_22\file.txt
```

Comment: sample data and expected output would help. also as you mention in the question, look up `distinct` in sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need distinct for this, just group data bys csv location and select the max date for it

```
SELECT CsvLocation, MAX(ExportedDate)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY CsvLocation
```

Comment: Thats it cheers. I was looking at using distinct on the CSVLocation column and wasnt sure how to work it from that angle. Thanks